# How do I make Warning messages stop printing in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Visual studio 2010 output window is constantly printing out "Warning:" message on output window. I would like to make it not print out those messages. How should I accomplish this?
Thanks. (of course getting rid of the message is the best solution but at the moment I just want to hide those messages)

Answer (score 0):

In the properties dialog for your project, you can change the warning level to 0 to turn off all warnings.

Instructions can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13b90fz7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

1. Open the project's Properties page
2. Click the Build property page.
3. Modify the Warning Level property.